# Implementing Ajax deferred/promise patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a testcase where I want to send a request to the server every time a form field `change` event occurs.  The implementation below works as expected until I submit the form and check for any empty values(*this is the only front-end validation carried out, the rest is done via ajax*). If a field is empty I trigger a `change` event so validation can be carried out on the server side.

In the example below I had to set `async=>false` so each trigger would work as expected.  I realize this is not ideal and there is a better way around this using deferred/promise patterns.

I am already using somewhat of the pattern `.promise` and `.then` however I think I need to use the `.when` method but I am unsure how to work it into my partially working example.

I am also a little unsure of the amount of request's being sent to the server. Is it viable to send this many, i.e.: each time an event occurs?

*Please ignore the block comments, I just use them for code separation.*

```
(function($){
var Registration= {};

/**
 * 
 * @type type
**/
Registration.fields = {};    
/**
 * 
 * @type type
**/
Registration.options = {
    cache       : false,
    type        : 'POST',
    dataType    : 'json',
    url         : SITE_URL + '/members/validateFieldOnChange',
    context     : undefined,
    data        : undefined,
    async       : false    // TODO
};
/**
 * 
 * @returns {undefined}
**/
Registration.init = function(){

    //caching
    this.Form = $('form#form-register');

    this.fields = {
        username    : this.Form.find('#username'),
        email       : this.Form.find('#email'),
        password    : this.Form.find('#password'),
    };   

    // register event handlers
    this.Form.on('change', 'input', $.proxy(this.handleEvents, this));
    this.Form.on('submit', $.proxy(this.handleEvents, this));
};
/**
 * 
 * @param {type} event
 * @returns {undefined}
**/
Registration.handleEvents = function(event){   
    var type, target 

    event.preventDefault();

    type   = event.type;
    target = event.target;

    if(type == 'change'){
        return this.handleChangeEvent(event.target);
    }

    return this.handleSubmitEvent();      
};

/**
 * 
 * @param {type} target
 * @returns {undefined}
**/
Registration.handleChangeEvent = function(target){

    this.options.context = target;

    this.options.data = { field : target.name, value : target.value}

    return this.validate();
};

/**
 * 
 * @returns {undefined}
**/
Registration.handleSubmitEvent = function(){

    // Ugly testcase if values are empty
    // TODO
    if($('#username').val() == ''){
        $('#username').trigger('change');
    }

    if($('#email').val() == ''){
        $('#email').trigger('change');
    }

    if($('#password').val() == ''){
        $('#password').trigger('change');
    }

};
/**
 * 
 * @returns {_L2.Registration@call;doAjax@call;then}
**/
Registration.validate = function(){
    return this.doAjax().then(
        $.proxy(this.handleResponse, this),
        $.proxy(this.handleError, this)
    );
};

/**
 * 
 * @param {type} response
 * @returns {undefined}
**/
Registration.handleResponse = function(response){

    var field = $(this.options.context);

    if(response.msg == 'success')
    {
        field.addClass('valid');
    }
    else
    {
        field.val('');
        field.attr('placeholder', response.responseError);
        field.addClass('invalid');
    }

    return;
};
/**
 * 
 * @param {type} error
 * @returns {undefined}
**/
Registration.handleError = function(error){
    switch(error.code)
    {
        case 404:
            return console.error('Not found');
        break;
        case 401:
            return console.error('un-authorized access!');
        break;
        case 500:
            return console.error('system error!');
        break;
    }
};

/**
 * 
 * @returns {unresolved}
**/
Registration.doAjax = function(){
    return $.ajax(this.options).promise();
}

Registration.init();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I'm not clear on why you currently have a need to use `async: false`. You are using promises, so which part of this requires the request to be synchronous?

Comment: `.trigger('change')` requires the request(s) to be synchronous. This is not ideal hence the need for a workaround.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why `trigger` would require the requests to be synchronous. The triggering of events should be disconnected from what they actually do. Or is this because you have three `trigger`s in succession and the requests are trampling each other?

Comment: @JLRishe that's exactly it. The three `triggers` are getting called in succession.

Comment: I think you're going to have some trouble trying to wait on the asynchronous outcome of an event, because of that separation I mentioned. Could you have your test cases instead call `handleChangeEvent` directly and wait on its outcome (using `.then`)? I think that should allow you to do what you need to do.